# Como identificar um erro http (500) através do selenium web driver ou javascript

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, http-status

Preciso montar um script que varra determinadas páginas e localize erros http, específico o 500. Pensei em fazer um script selenium, porém não sei um comando que eu consiga "ler" esse tipo de erro. Alguém sabe me dizer se o selenium tem algum comando para isso, ou javascript?

Comment: Qual linguagem você está usando para programar o Selenium?

Comment: Estou utilizando Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alguém sabe me dizer se o selenium tem algum comando para isso, ou javascript?

O Selenium em si, não. O que você pode fazer é disparar uma requisição usando uma sessão compartilhada e recolher o status de erro.

O pacote que sei que faz isso é o [`selenium-requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium-requests/). Um exemplo:

```
from seleniumrequests import *

browser = Firefox();
# Faça algumas ações aqui, como autenticar login, se for o caso.
retorno_requisicao = browser.request('GET', "http://sitequalquer.com")
if retorno_requisicao.status_code >= 500:
    # Trate os erros aqui.
```